# Conditional constraints in Integer Linear Programming

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming, integer-programming, np-complete, binary-programming

I think it's rather a simple question. I'm trying to construct a reduction from graph problem to ILP. When I have variables $x_1, x_2, \dots ,x_n \in \{0, 1\}$ for every vertex, can I create constrains only for variables that have specific value? For example:
$$\forall [x_i|x_i=1]\sum_{j\in N(i)}x_j=some\_value$$

Is this a legal in ILP? Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to enforce the logical implication
$$x_i = 1 \implies \sum_{j\in N(i)} x_j = k.$$
This is not a linear constraint, but you can linearize it via linear "big-M" constraints
$$-k(1-x_i) \le \sum_{j\in N(i)} x_j - k \le (|N(i)|-k)(1-x_i)$$

- If $x_i=1$, then
  $$0 \le \sum_{j\in N(i)} x_j - k \le 0,$$
  equivalently,
  $$\sum_{j\in N(i)} x_j = k,$$
  as desired.
- If $x_i=0$, then
  $$-k \le \sum_{j\in N(i)} x_j - k \le |N(i)|-k,$$
  equivalently,
  $$0 \le \sum_{j\in N(i)} x_j \le |N(i)|,$$
  which is redundant, as desired.

Comment: Thanks! It works as expected. I was also trying to come up with similar equation but for inequality where $\sum_{j\in N(i)} x_j \leq k$ but i failed. If you know the answer could you also provide it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: To enforce just the $\le k$ inequality, omit the $-k(1-x_i)\le$ part.